# The insert into BigQuery is taking too long to become available for selection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the code below that compiles and runs without any errors. In the return of the insert, `insertResponse`, there are no errors, and if I, for example, omit a required value, I do get an error, so the BigQuery client is indeed successfully reaching BigQuery.

I know there is a latency in insertion, but I waited minutes, invalidated the query, and still, no data appears. I have inserted more than five times, and there are no data in the BigQuery console!

How can I solve this?

```
  const rowsToAppend = bigQuerySchema.parse(
    caloriesMap.map(
      (calorie) =>
        ({
          start: new Date(calorie.start),
          end: new Date(calorie.start + calorie.duration),
          duration_in_milis: calorie.duration,
          label: calorie.label,
          collar_nano_id: calorie.id,
          calories: calorie.calories,
          intensity_label: 'moderate', // TODO
        }) satisfies Flatten<BigQueryWalkRow>,
    ),
  )

  const dataset = bigquery.dataset(BIGQUERY_DATASET)
  const table = dataset.table(BIGQUERY_ACTIVITIES_TABLE)
  const [insertResponse] = await table.insert(rowsToAppend)
  console.log('>>>> insertResponse', insertResponse)
```

Comment: Did you query the data or perform a preview on the table?

Comment: Both, in both case nothing is showed. No data.

Comment: Can you share the logs of the insertion job you have?